# Defining models outside of models folder. RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm writing tests for my app, and I ran into an issue.  My team works only on reading from the database, never writing and for many tables we do not have ruby models for them.  Those tables are only used in joins (hardcoded table names in .joins).

I'm trying to create some test data  using factory_girl and I wanted to avoid using .sql files for inserts.  So for tables without models I was attempting to create a MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base only to be loaded in test environment and want to keep this in maybe a spec/ folder.  It doesn't seem like config.autoload_paths << "spec/factories" in the application.rb is enough.  I get an error saying MyModel is not a class.

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a test_helper or spec_helper class where you can require the test files. Otherwise you can require it directly from whichever test needs it.

Avoid loading these in application.rb, since files required there will get loaded for development and production environments as well.

Answer (score 1):

Files (and folders) in `spec/support` are auto-loaded by `spec_helper`, you could make a `spec/support/fake_models` folder and put your fake models in there.